# Line in script does not match spoken line in The Big Lebowski

Tags: coen-brothers, the-big-lebowski

Reading the script for "The Big Lebowski" at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tfTyDwTFd-3RgYrYDzT2bhpFA-gHUrFEaHy1R8mLF94/edit it reads:

```
DUDE
        You see a wedding ring?  Does this 
        place look like I'm fucking married?   
        All my plants are dead!
```

But in the movie The Dude states "The toilet seat is up man" instead of "All my plants are dead!". Was this improvised or a mistake in the script posted?

Comment: No direct answer to the question but it's not uncommon that the script differs from the movie.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. As Charmin states, scripts often don't match the dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line was probably changed to a funnier/clearer one. It isn't uncommon that scripts differ from actual movies, professional acting and directing not always require to follow every word of the script.

Comment: Downvote. This isn't any different that what Charmin said in the comment. Unless you have anything substantial to add as an answer this would have been better as a comment.